# Как в админке django сделать проверку на создание дублирующихся сущностей

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель с созданием подборок товаров. В подборке указаны позиции товаров.
Модель товаров:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Название", max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField("Описание", default='')
    price = models.DecimalField("Цена", default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Создано", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Обновлено", auto_now=True)
    product_collection = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductCollections,
        verbose_name="Подборки",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="products")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def get_review(self):
        return self.review.all()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Товар"
        verbose_name_plural = "Товары"
```

Модель подборок товаров:

```
class ProductCollections(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Создано", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Обновлено", auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_productlistforcollection(self):
        return self.productlistforcollection.all()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Подборка"
        verbose_name_plural = "Подборки"
```

Далее модель позиций:

```
class ProductListForCollection(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_list')
    collection = models.ForeignKey(ProductCollections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Позиция"
        verbose_name_plural = "Позиции"
```

В сериализаторе есть проверка на создание дублирующихся товаров в списке подборок:

```
class AddProductToCollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductListForCollection
        fields = ('collection', 'product')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return ProductListForCollection.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def validate(self, data):
        post_data = self.context["request"].data
        collection_id = post_data.get('collection')
        product_id = post_data.get('product')
        product_name = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        collection_items = ProductListForCollection.objects.filter(collection_id=collection_id)
        for item in collection_items:
            if str(product_name) == str(item):
                raise ValidationError({"ProductListForCollection": "Товар уже есть в списке"})
        return data
```

Это всё работает, но при создании позиций через админку - нет. Насколько я знаю для валидаций в админке нужно использовать формы. Вот пример формы, которую я добавляю в админку:

```
class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_product(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['product']
        print(data)
        return data
```

Она выдаёт в консоль "список" товаров, который, понятное дело, списком не является. Как я понял, функция clean_product отрабатывает столько раз, сколько сущностей найдёт, выдавая каждый раз по одному товару и если попытаться их посчитать, то просто покажет единицы. Как проверить содержится ли уже добавляемый через админку товар в списке подборки так же, как это проверяется в сериализаторе? Может код не совсем красив, но это моя первая работа - прошу сильно не пинать)

Comment: Добавь к вопросу описание `Product` модели

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, добавил модель `Product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если тебе достаточно будет того, что не будет повторяющихся значений на основе (id), тогда тебе достаточно поправить  модель `ProductListForCollection`

```
class ProductListForCollection(models.Model):
...

    class Meta:
    ...
    unique_together = ('product', 'collection')
```

подробней https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#index-together

если же по каким-то причинам ты хочешь иметь в классе Product несколько позиций с одним и тем же наименованием(`name`) и тебе нужно, что бы в `ProductListForCollection` для каждой коллекции не было товаров с одним наименованием, тогда можно вынести валидацию из сериализатора, непосредственно в модель:

```
class ProductListForCollection(models.Model):
...
    def clean():
        if self.product:
            count_name_usage = ProductListForCollection.objects.filter(
                collection=self.collection, 
                product__name=self.product.name
            ).exclude(id=self.id).count()
            if count_name_usage > 0:
                raise ValidationError('В данной коллекции уже есть товар с таким именем')
```

подробней о валидации данных в Model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!